# MDN ADD-ON SDK Geolocation ERROR: XPCWrappedNative_NoHelper - "NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_IID"

Tags: geolocation, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

---

If anyone else has come across **XPCWrappedNative_NoHelper - "NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_IID"** issue while trying to geolocate a user while building a mozilla add-on with geolocation from there tutorial  I have a solution for you.

---

**Current Code (that returns error)
"[click here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/reusable-modules.html)"**

---

**Working Code (that works)**

```
const {components, Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
function getCurrentPosition(callback) {
    var xpcomGeolocation = Cc["@mozilla.org/geolocation;1"].getService(Ci.nsISupports);
    xpcomGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
}

var widget = require("sdk/widget").Widget({
    id: "whereami",
    label: "Where am I?",
    contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
    onClick: function() {
        getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            console.log("latitude: ", position.coords.latitude);
            console.log("longitude: ", position.coords.longitude);
        });
    }
});
```